# Sonar Performance - Static inner class of Type Token

Tags: java, generics

Sonar says "Performance - Could be refactored into a named static inner class The class DataServiceImpl$2 could be refactored into a named static inner class".

```
paramsClass1.add(new TypeToken<List<EntityFieldMap>>(){}.getType());
```

So created a static class and it works fine but when i make it generic it is not working. Look at this snippet.

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
public class TokenTest
{
    public static class MyInnerClass1<T> extends TypeToken<T> {};
    public static class MyInnerClass2<Integer> extends TypeToken<Integer> {};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //prints T
        System.out.println(new MyInnerClass1<Integer>().getType());
        //prints Integer which is desired
        System.out.println(new MyInnerClass2().getType());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Something is being silly here. The suggestion is a premature optimization, the root of all evil. You are not even running it in a loop. Even if you did it shouldn't matter unless the compiler is really silly (the code is equivalent).

Comment: @JanHudec: I agree. If anything this *could possibly* be a maintenance problem, but I don't see how this ever could be a "performance" problem ...

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Well, I consider it a maintenance problem to _follow_ the advice, because anonymous class is simply more readable here.

Comment: @JanHudec: I also agree with this, but what I wanted to say is: no matter which side of the argument you lean to, it's in the wrong *category* altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeToken` is special, because it actually depends on that anonymous class. And the reason why your generified-type-token doesn't work is the reason why `TypeToken` exists in the first place! Generics will be erased at runtime. Extending a generic class with a fixed type-parameter is a way to get around that restriction.

See the [JavaDoc of Guava `TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) (I know you're talking about GSON, but the use and functionality is the same in both libraries, and the Guava one has better documentation):

> Note that it's critical that the actual type argument is carried by a subclass. The following code is wrong because it only captures the `<T>` type variable of the `listType()` method signature; while `<String>` is lost in erasure:
>
> ```
> class Util {
>   static <T> TypeToken<List<T>> listType() {
>     return new TypeToken<List<T>>() {};
>   }
> }
>
> TypeToken<List<String>> stringListType = Util.<String>listType();
> ```

My suggestion: ignore this warning for `TypeToken` (ideally in an automated fashion, alternatively by manually adding exceptions).

Comment: Is there another way to get the type?